# javascript-getelement

Tags: javascript

what type of values given to getElementById() method

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` expects a string.

The following code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId');
```

finds the following element and assigns it to `element`

```
<div id="myId"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just pass the id of any element 
like `<input type="text" id="text" />`
just use `getElementById("text")`

Answer (score 0):

a single DOM object, of a specialized class depending on the nature of the element identified by the given ID